# uninstalled gnome extensions keep reappearing

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I have a very weird, and extremely annoying, problem.
Each time after reboot (or logout), old uninstalled extensions that I tried out and decided not for me, reinstall themselves. I have to go tho gnome extension in Firefox and uninstall them.
Side Issue: for some reason, I can't remove extensions with pending updates. So I update the extensions I wish to remove, which is completely backwards. This would not be an issue given the main issue wasn't there.
I checked the directory ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions . Only desired extensions appear there in ls -a.

Thanks in Advance,
Gal

Answer (score 1):

Some extensions are installed in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Try checking in that path. You'll need root privileges